# How to read output of crs() in the Terra package in R

Tags: r, gis, terra, map-projections

I have a SpatRaster and I want to figure out the EPSG code of it. I have used the `crs()` command and I got the following output:

```
PROJCRS["unknown",
        BASEGEOGCRS["NAD83",
                    DATUM["North American Datum 1983",
                          ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101004,
                                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
                    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                           ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                    ID["EPSG",4269]],
        CONVERSION["Albers Equal Area",
                   METHOD["Albers Equal Area",
                          ID["EPSG",9822]],
                   PARAMETER["Latitude of false origin",23,
                             ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                             ID["EPSG",8821]],
                   PARAMETER["Longitude of false origin",-96,
                             ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                             ID["EPSG",8822]],
                   PARAMETER["Latitude of 1st standard parallel",29.5,
                             ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                             ID["EPSG",8823]],
                   PARAMETER["Latitude of 2nd standard parallel",45.5,
                             ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                             ID["EPSG",8824]],
                   PARAMETER["Easting at false origin",0,
                             LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                             ID["EPSG",8826]],
                   PARAMETER["Northing at false origin",0,
                             LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                             ID["EPSG",8827]]],
        CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["easting",east,
             ORDER[1],
             LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                        ID["EPSG",9001]]],
        AXIS["northing",north,
             ORDER[2],
             LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                        ID["EPSG",9001]]]]
```

As you can see, there are multiple different numbers after the word EPSG and I am unsure how to read it and figure out what actually is the EPSG of my data. Can someone help me with that? Below is a reproducible example:

Get the SpatRaster data. To download it on Linux using the R package `CropscapeR` I need to do the process below (in Windows it is easier):

```
library(CropScapeR)
library(terra)
# Skip the SSL check
httr::set_config(httr::config(ssl_verifypeer = 0L))
# Automatically generate a temporary path to save the data
tif_file <- tempfile(fileext = '.tif')
# Download the raster TIF file into specified path, also read into R
# This is a county in Iowa, US
ST_CDL <- GetCDLData(aoi = '19001', year = 2020, type = 'f', save_path = tif_file) 
terra::writeRaster(ST_CDL, "ST_CDL.tif", overwrite=TRUE)
ST_CDL = terra::rast("ST_CDL.tif")
```

The command I run that gives me the output shown above.

```
crs(ST_CDL)
```

I want to figure out what the EPSG code is in order to `terra::project()` a SpatVector I have to the crs of my SpatRaster above. However, I was afraid `terra::project(my_spatvector, crs(ST_CDL))` would give me the wrong output if crs(ST_CDL) is PROJ.4, since the [documentation](https://rdrr.io/github/rspatial/terra/man/project.html) for this functions says "note that the PROJ.4 notation has been deprecated, and you can only use it with the WGS84/NAD83 and NAD27 datums. Other datums are silently ignored."

Comment: I'm guessing you used a different `crs` function. I get different output (although yours looks much nicer.) There is an SE forum for GIS questions. You should subscribe, do a search on how to read CRS descriptions, and then delete this question, regardless of whether there is a good Q&A. This is not a coding question, and SO is not designed to fill in general stats confusions, much less fill in missing training in specialized applications..

Comment: `GetCDLData()`  reurns  `raster` , and  `crs(ST_CDL)`  can be either `raster::crs()` or `terra::crs()`, depending on when it gets called -- before or after reusing same object name for a terra object.

Comment: There are only very (*very*) few CRSs that have an EPSG code (This is obvious because the number of CRSs is ~infinite, you cannot have a database of all of them). But there is no need to worry about that. "terra" uses WKT2 to define CRSs, that is what matters.

Answer (score 1):

There's a good chance that the used CRS does not perfectly match any of the registered EPSG codes. Though I don't see any real issues here, by default `terra::crs()` returns CRS as a WKT string (as you demonstrate in your question), to get PROJ-string you'd have to force it by using `terra::crs(ST_CDL, proj = TRUE)` .

`CropScapeR::GetCDLData()` in your example saves TIF, returns `RasterLayer`, which you then convert to `SpatRaster` and save to another TIF. So perhaps just skip that `raster` to `terra` conversion and open the downloaded file directly with `terra`:

```r
tif_file <- "ST_CDL.tif"
# set readr = FALSE to skip reading downloaded file with  
# raster::raster(save_path)
CropScapeR::GetCDLData(aoi = '19001', year = 2020, type = 'f', save_path = tif_file, readr = FALSE) 
#> Data is saved at:ST_CDL.tif
#> NULL

# read with terra
ST_CDL <- terra::rast(tif_file)
ST_CDL
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 1312, 1292, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 30, 30  (x, y)
#> extent      : 107655, 146415, 2017395, 2056755  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : NAD83_Conus_Albers 
#> source      : ST_CDL.tif 
#> color table : 1 
#> name        : Layer_1

# using terra::crs() result for vector crs is fine, 
# crs() returns PROJ-string only if you explicitly set proj to TRUE:
terra::crs(ST_CDL, proj = TRUE)
#> [1] "+proj=aea +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: great suggestion on opening directly as a rast. Is there any way of knowing is the CRS does not perfectly match any of the registered EPSG codes?

Comment: You can get a custom WKT string of the file with `sf::gdal_crs("ST_CDL.tif")` (the "User input" part) and then compare it to some close matches, i.e. EPSG:5070 (as referenced by https://www.nass.usda.gov/Research_and_Science/Cropland/sarsfaqs2.php and reported by QGIS), precision for datum ellipsoid is higher than in https://epsg.org/crs/wkt/id/5070  / https://epsg.io/5070 . While It makes virtually no difference, the CRS in question is most likely not sourced from EPSG dataset.